# WSL2 preferred startup method

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I just installed WSL2 on my Windows 10 box with an Ubuntu backend, and have noticed I now have at least 3 different ways that I can start a Linux shell via `Start` + `Run`:

- `bash`
- `ubuntu`
- `wsl`

I was surprised to stumble across three different methods of doing what looks like the same thing.

What's the difference between them, if any?

Is there a preferred method to start up a Linux shell in WSL2?

[image: Three shells with 3 distinctly different icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, two different questions.  I'll take the second question first:

#### *First question - Is there a preferred method to start up a Linux shell in WSL2?*

IMHO, the preferred method of launching into a WSL instance is the new Windows Terminal from/by Microsoft, available in the Microsoft Store or in [open source form](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) on Github.  Windows Terminal will, with its default settings, automatically detect any installed WSL distributions and create a menu launcher for them.  It's by far the most feature rich of the terminals available as a native Windows app, although it's also *possible* to install an X Server and use many of the myriad Linux GUI terminals as well.

Side tip:  I recommend installing a [Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) for the additional glyphs that they support.

#### *Second question - The difference between the three commands that you listed.*

There's a previous answer with some good detail copied from the Microsoft devblog.  I'll take a slightly different approach than the previous answer, with some more detail:

- `wsl.exe` (or just `wsl` under cmd or PowerShell) is the newest of the three that you mention. There are a number of additional options that can be used with `wsl`.  See [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference) for more information.  Among the options are:

  - Launching into a different distro or instance
  - Launching into the default or a different distro as any user (very convenient for
    root)
  - Exporting a distro/instance for backup or cloning purposes
  - Re-importing a previously exported distro - To either restore a backup or to clone an instance.
  - Set the default WSL version (1 or 2)
  - Change the version for an existing instance/distro
- `ubuntu`:  This is just an "App execution alias" for the Microsoft Store (formerly known as "UWP") app.  It will only appear when you install through the store.  You can see it in the Windows app execution aliases settings screen.

  It has the same effect as if you launched the **app**, which is to launch the default Ubuntu install in the "Ubuntu Terminal" (horrible name, but I've found references on the Canonical website calling it this).  I'm not sure what the "real" terminal behind this is, but it is a bit buggy and doesn't seem supported.
- `bash`:  According to [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#additional-commands), `bash` is a "historic command" that is "still available for use."  That seems to me to be one step short of "deprecated", honestly.

Comment: Note: Windows Terminal is about a million times better than I expected it to be. I highly recommend it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The article
[A Guide to Invoking WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/)
explains the subtle differences between each invocation, where
each is slightly different:

> **wsl**
>
> The first (and recommended!) method will start up your default distro.
> Additionally, it starts the distro in the current working directory
> where you invoke the command. You can change the default distro by
> using the “wslconfig” tool.
>
> **ubuntu*
>
> Alternatively, you can specify by name the exact distro you want to
> launch. We now have several distros in the store and there might be
> cases where you wish to launch a distro which is not labeled as your
> default. Using Ubuntu as the example, it’s as simple as calling
> “ubuntu”. This will launch into the distro userland with default
> shell.
>
> **bash**
>
> This will attempt to start bash in your default distro. Even if you’ve
> configured the distro to have another default shell (take zsh for
> example), it will still try to launch bash.